# Solving a logical exercise in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to study Prolog, and i have some troubles with logical exercise.

> Bob, Tom, Sam have a job in bank as an accountant, cashier and manager.
>   Here are some more facts about them:
>
> - If Sam - cashier, than Tom - manager.
> - If Sam - manager, Tom - accountant.
> - If Tom is not cashier, Bob - not manager.
> - If Bob - accountant, Sam - manager.
>
> Find out Tom, Sam and Bob's profession.

Comment: we could have some idea, please show yours!

Comment: Prolog is very hard for me=( I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: You can have a list of persons  **[[sam, WS], [tom, WT], [bob, WB]]** and a list of jobs  [accountant, cashier, manager], each person has a job taken in the list of jobs, all are different and the list of persons must verify the four rules you describe.

Comment: Go ahead and look at http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online should be able to solve the problem with a couple of hours of reading and trying things out.

Comment: Are you sure those rules are complete? I get 3 solutions...

Comment: Сapellic, yes there are 3 solutions:
1) Sam - manager, Tom -accountant , Bob - cashier.
2) Sam- accountant, Tom - manager, Bob - cashier. 
3) Sam - accountant, Tom - cashier, Bob - manager.

Comment: @joel76: I don't think your formula is correct...

Comment: @CapelliC : Yes, I saw this morning the bug in my code !

Answer (score 0):

Given the small dataset, you can solve using **generate and test**, see [permutation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=permutation/2)/2 . To easy translate each rule, name a variable with the worker name. I'll show just the first condition

```
q([sam=Sam, tom=Tom, bob=Bob]) :-
  ...,
  ( Sam = cashier -> Tom = manager ; true ),
  ....
```

with that, i get these solutions

```
?- q(X).
X = [sam=accountant, tom=cashier, bob=manager] ;
X = [sam=manager, tom=accountant, bob=cashier] ;
X = [sam=accountant, tom=manager, bob=cashier] ;
false.
```

Comment: thanks alot i've made something working
`q([sam/A, tom/B, bob/C]) :-
N=[accountan,cashier,manager],
P=[A,B,C],
permute(N,P),
  ( accountan = B -> cashier = C ; true ),
 ( accountan = C -> cashier = A ; true ),
( not(cashier = B) -> not(manager = C) ; true ),
 ( manager = A -> accountan = C ; true ).

append([],B,B).
append([H|T],B,[H|T1]):-append(T,B,T1).

insert(Y,XZ,XYZ):-append(X,Z,XZ),append(X,[Y],XY),append(XY,Z,XYZ).

permute([],[]).
permute([H|T],L):-permute(T,T1),insert(H,T1,L).`